# Can't delete nignx's temporary files without sudo

Tags: nginx, archlinux

I've installed nginx the regular way on Arch Linux. Anytime my website (ie nginx) creates temporary files, it's created by the `http:http` user and they have 755 permission.

I need to clear the cache time to time and I am logged as a regular user. That means anytime I need to delete those files, I need to use `sudo` which isn't right for number of reasons. What is the right method to be able delete those files without sudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, this is just the way it ought to be. Semantics around creating and using tempfiles are tricky and the root of many security problems. Don't try to subvert this.

The real question is, why are you deleting these files? Are they never deleted or reused or otherwise managed by the nginx process? If there is a problem there, then solve *that* problem. Don't go chasing after the permissions that a running process uses to create tempfiles unless you really, *really*, **really** have to. (For example, if you are writing those files to some special file system. But even this is a weak reason.)

But, if you occasionally have to delete files created by UIDs not you, you need to do it as that UID or as a privileged user. There are ways to tweak sudo such that you can control how much a sudoer can do (say that seven times really fast.)

Comment: The usecase: I'm working on a website. It creates its temp files in its `temp/` folder and eveything is beautiful. But time to time I need to work with the project's 'console'. That's a Symfony/Console php thing, which allows me to run migrations, run tests etc. This console needs a temp as well. However whenever it tries to access `temp/` it can't, because the `temp/` folder was created by `http` but I ran the console as `user`.

Comment: First of all, you need to be clear if you mean it is trying to write to /tmp (note the absolute path) or a "tmp" directory inside a possibly `chroot`ed environment. Looks like you have two choices: (1) run your console as the http user (probably not possible) or root, or (2) change the temp location used by the console process. Don't hack nginx to get this to fit. Tweak the tools or environment they run in to solve the problem. However, I don't know what this chunk of PHP is or does, so you are going to have to research. Can't the PHP be run with a special TEMP environment, or passed a flag?

Comment: I've realized it's not clear as well, so I editted to `temp/` to make it a bit clearer that I ment my own temp folder. Ok, thank you, I'll have a look into this.